# Neo4J Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel

Tags: java, servlets, neo4j, cypher

I just moved my Cypher query from version 1.8.2 to 2.0 and this line of Cypher code fails

```
    start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n 
where  HAS(n.taxnumber) AND NOT(n IN nodes(p)[1..-1]) 
return extract(s in relationships(p) :s.amount), 
extract(t in nodes(p) :ID(t)), length(p) ;
```

I get an error on ID(t) saying

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [SeeTheResults] in context with path [/DebtSolutions] threw exception
Invalid input '(': expected an identifier character, whitespace, NodeLabel, '.', node labels, '[', "=~", IN, IS, '*', '/', '%', '^', '+', '-', '<', '>', "<=", ">=", '=', "<>", "!=", AND, XOR, OR, WHERE, '|', ')' or ',' (line 1, column 174)
"start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n where  HAS(n.taxnumber) AND NOT(n IN nodes(p)[1..-1]) return extract(s in relationships(p) :s.amount), extract(t in nodes(p) :ID(t)), length(p) ;"
                                                                                                                                                                              ^
```

The error is pointing  on id(t) .

On version 1.8.2 the query was

```
start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n 
where  HAS(n.taxnumber) [1..-1]) 
return extract(s in relationships(p) :s.amount), 
extract(t in nodes(p) :ID(t)), length(p) ;
```

because 1.8.2 did not support AND NOT(n IN nodes(p)[1..-1]) , and if I move this part from 2.0 version it fails the same way.
The graph displays a relation between companies of OWE with relation property AMOUNT, that is how much .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated the answer in the other question for 1.8.

If you move the query to 2.0 you have to replace `:` in extract, filter etc. with `|`.

```
start n=node(*) match p=n-[r:OWES*1..200]->n 
where  HAS(n.taxnumber) AND NOT(n IN nodes(p)[1..-1]) 
return extract(s in relationships(p) | s.amount), 
       extract(t in nodes(p) | ID(t)), length(p)
```

Comment: When I use 'AND NOT(n IN nodes(p)[1..-1])' I get none results at all, but the query now works.

Comment: I again get double results .